# Running julia on google colab

Tags: julia, google-colaboratory

I'm trying to run julia on google colab, but it does not work for some reason.

I'm using this template: https://colab.research.google.com/github/ageron/julia_notebooks/blob/master/Julia_Colab_Notebook_Template.ipynb

I can run the first cell without issues, but it doesn't run anything else without errors. It basically doesnt recognize julia syntax after installation. Any ideas what I'm doing wrong?

Edit: Sometimes, when I try to run the installation cell I get this error:

/usr/local/lib/python3.8/dist-packages/google/colab/_system_commands.py in check_returncode(self)
132   def check_returncode(self):
133     if self.returncode:
--> 134       raise subprocess.CalledProcessError(
135           returncode=self.returncode, cmd=self.args, output=self.output)
136

CalledProcessError: Command 'set -e

' returned non-zero exit status 134.

Sometimes there is no errors, but there is no any output either and cant run any julia code.

Answer (score 0):

After running the cell, you need to follow step 4 in the instructions:

> Reload this page (press Ctrl+R, or ⌘+R, or the F5 key) and continue to the next section.

Comment: I did this but still not working..

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue; it could be resolved by restarting runtime.

Answer (score 0):

I have exactly the same issue and nothing was working!!
But I found that if you run Julia code not on your own notebook but on the **copy of the notebook of Julia's colab template**.. then you will be able to run Julia commands successfully!!

Also if you have run the template code on you own notebook then you must run that copy of the template through some other google account.. otherwise it may not work.....